# Database connection Error - Using NETLIFY

Tags: node.js, netlify, remote-connection

I have this project where I need to insert the content of a website to my local SQL Server.
This website has a webhook feature where I can connect using a valid URL.

I have to use this webhook to track the changes that are made on this site.

So, I'm using Netlify to create a valid URL and then creating a function to re-direct the content received from the webhook to my local server, where I already configured ports, firewalls and IPs Fowardings.

But when I deploy de function to Netlify, trigger the webhook, and check the log of the function, it says that it couldn't connect to my server.

```
12:10:43 PM: 4935afd1 ERROR  Unhandled Promise Rejection
    {"errorType":"Runtime.UnhandledPromiseRejection","errorMessage":"ConnectionError:
Failed to connect to <my_external_ip>:<my_port> in
15000ms"
```

Here is the code that i deploy in Netlify:

```
const connStr = "Server=<my_external_ip>,<my_port>;Database=<my_db>;User Id=<my_usr>;Password=<my_pass>;trustServerCertificate=true;";
const sql = require("mssql");

exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
  try {
    const body = JSON.parse(event.body); 
    
    // Inicio do Banco
    teste = sql.connect(connStr)
    .then(conn => insertTable(connStr, body))
    .catch(err => console.log("erro! " + err));


    function insertTable(conn, body){
      const col1 = body.col1
      const col2 = body.col2
      const col3 = body.col3
            
      new sql.Request().query(`INSERT INTO <TABLE_NAME> (COL1, COL2, COL3) VALUES ('${col1}', '${col2}', ${col3})`, (err, result) => {
      console.dir(result)
    })
}
    // Fim do Banco

    console.log("Submitted!");
    return {
      statusCode: 204,
    };
  } catch (err) {
    return { statusCode: 500, body: err.toString() };
  }
};
```

I think my server's configuration is ok because I can remotely connect through SSMS to my database.

Comment: So this is your "local SQL Server" but you can "can remotely connect through SSMS"? If the netlify (remote) website needs to connect to your local network DB you need to open a port for the db.

Comment: Yeah, I think that I say "local" wrong. In my head, I was thinking local because it is a SQL Server that runs inside my local network default.
Anyway... when I change the network, I still can access this SQL Server with SSMS (but not with Netlify).
Any other idea?